# Convert BCD encoded hexadecimal value into timestamp / data and time ( ASN.1 syntax)

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, bouncycastle

Hi i have hexadecimal string of time stamp generated by MSC (is a neighbouring base stations keeps a record of the location of the mobile subscribers). Now I want to convert hexadecimal string to human readable date and time.

Hear actual hexadecimal string variable is a Octet String data type (ASN.1 syntax)

let me give a example how the hexadecimal string look like

```
hexadecimal value : 1307301826042B0530
```

hear the hexadecimal value formed by converting BCD encoded timestamp as bellow

```
Local time of UTC compression format
--YY    =   Year 00 to 99       BCD encoded
--MM    =   Month 01 to 12      BCD encoded
--DD    =   Day 01 to 31        BCD encoded
-- hh   =   hour 00 to 23       BCD encoded
-- mm   =   minute 00 to 59     BCD encoded
-- ss   =   second 00 to 59     BCD encoded
-- S    =   Sign 0 = “+”, “-“       ASCII encoded
-- hh   =   hour 00 to 23       BCD encoded
-- mm   =   minute 00 to 59     BCD encoded
```

So bellow table shows time stamp of Octet String

```
in ASN.1 syntax it look like  TimeStamp ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE(9))

Octet 1 YY
Octet 2 MM
Octet 3 DD
Octet 4 hh
Octet 5 mm
Octet 6 ss
Octet 7 S
Octet 8 hh
Octet 9 mm
```

So according to above table the hex value can be divided as fallow

```
 Hex value : 1307301826042B0530

    Octet 1 YY  : 13  
    Octet 2 MM  : 07
    Octet 3 DD  : 30
    Octet 4 hh  : 18            Hear every octet is of one byte each
    Octet 5 mm  : 26
    Octet 6 ss  : 04 
    Octet 7 S  :  2B
    Octet 8 hh  : 05
    Octet 9 mm  : 30
```

So to convert hex to time stamp / date and time i did as bellow

First i converted each hex byte into a BCD and BCD to binary and binary to decimal then i got

```
Decimal : 685571919861616
```

then i tried to convert into date and time

```
        String decimal = "685571919861616";
        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(decimal));

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
```

But output was like `23694-11-28 09:54:21`

even i tried to convert hex to decimal then to convert decimal into date and time using java but output was like `8227-12-21 02:24:03`

pleas help me on this and i would like to know is there any class present in Bouncy castle API to do this ...???

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before dealing with decoding of a encoded file we should have clear idea of how encoding was done after that it takes just a few seconds to solve above problem

As i said timestamp value of Octet string look like this

```
Hex value : 1307301826042B0530

    Octet 1 YY  : 13  
    Octet 2 MM  : 07
    Octet 3 DD  : 30
    Octet 4 hh  : 18            Hear every octet is of one byte each
    Octet 5 mm  : 26
    Octet 6 ss  : 04 
    Octet 7 S  :  2B
    Octet 8 hh  : 05
    Octet 9 mm  : 30
```

it clearly say that YY = 13 means 2013 like wise MM = 07 , DD = 30 , hh = 18 (24 hour format) .... etc

After analyzing i got shocked because it was so easy, for this i have braked my head for 2 days because i didn't have much information on how encoding is done.